# What is the difference between 飲む and 呑む?

Tags: nuances, homophonic-kanji, kanji-choice

I saw a tweet that said

```
要は日本酒が呑みたい
```

And my dictionary translated [呑む](http://jisho.org/search/%E5%91%91%E3%82%80) as 'to drink', with 飲む as the default spelling and 呑む as an alternate form.

What is the difference between 飲む and 呑む?

Comment: Your dictionary also says: 呑む is often used metaphorically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you know that to say "to take a pill" in Japanese you would say 丸薬をのむ. (I did not put the kanji of のむ intentionally).

飲む is used to say *to drink*. I mean, to absorb a liquid through your mouth like "to drink water, syrup, beer, ..."

On the other side 呑む is used more to mean *to swallow*. It can be figurative or not. 涙｛なみだ｝を呑｛の｝む (to refrain one's anger), 固唾｛かたず｝を呑む(to hold one's breath because of anxiety/fear), 息を呑む (to gasp).
町は闇に呑まれた (the village was in the dark).

Thus, the "right" spelling of 丸薬をのむ is with 呑む but today everyone uses 飲む (because 呑 is not part of the 常用漢字).

Comment: I find it interesting that *wonton* in Chinese is spelled 雲呑: "cloud swallowing".  Wonderfully poetic.

Comment: ...and contrary to explanations like [this](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1312052823), 呑む is widely used for sake drinking like here in [呑みきり](http://www.gokyo-sake.co.jp/tayori/22.html) and 立ち呑み all around towns

Comment: ...and it's hard to claim it is recent change, because for example of [黒田節](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%BB%92%E7%94%B0%E7%AF%80)

Comment: @macraf that is true that 呑む is also used for drinking sake but that is the only beverage I know for which 呑む is used and I preferred to omit it.

Comment: A couple more examples: 鵜{う}呑{の}み and 丸{まる}呑{の}み

Comment: As seen in the tweet in the question, it is true that some people do use 呑む to mean 酒を飲む these days (and they're not using 呑む for 薬 and 固唾!). [Novelists about 100 years ago mainly used (酒を)飲む](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/172444/example/m0u/) even though there was no 常用漢字表 yet. I don't know why, but maybe recent people were influenced by izakaya ads?

Comment: @naruto Interesting, I will try to get a hand on a 漢字漢和辞典 to clarify this. But I don't really get why Izakaya would write 呑む instead of 飲む. Maybe it's more hype?

Comment: Maybe. Someone might have thought swallowing sake is more suitable than just drinking sake, as an ad :-)